# Java Spring REST Interceptors

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need help. I wrote an interceptor who receives the request and checks, and return true or false, but if the data is true, server returned the Bad Request error.
This is my Interceptor:

```
@Component(value = "authInterceptor")
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
UserManager userManager;

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Interceptor");
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
        if (body != null) {
            log.info("Body is not null.");
            JsonObject model = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(body)).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(model.get("login").getAsString());
            if (!userManager.isRegisteredLogin(model.get("login").getAsString())) {
                log.error("Login is not authorized");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            log.error("Login is not authorized body is empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

}
}
```

And my controller:

```
    public ResponseEntity currentDate() {
           return new ResponseEntity<>(userController.getServerTime(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But the controller request does not reach

Comment: How have you configured with interceptor for controller ?

Comment: i hope this helps for your requirement: https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-rest-security/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml

Comment: with <mvc:interceptor>

Comment: can you add the <mvc:interceptor> configurations

Comment: <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/api/auth/**" />
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/api/login/**"/>
            <bean class="com.asbt.ps.interceptor.AuthInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>